# アプリからiPadの画面をロックするには

Tags: objective-c

アプリからiPadの画面をロックすることができないか調査しています。
色々調べてキオスクモードにたどりついたのですが、アプリからキオスクモードに切り替えることは可能なのでしょうか？
そもそもアプリからiPadの画面をロックすることは可能なのでしょうか？

アドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: sinsin さん  もし質問が解決した場合は回答にチェックを付けることをお勧めします。お互いの信頼度が上がり、今後の活動をより充実させることができます。[ヘルプセンター > 自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

アプリからキオスクモードにすることはできないはずです。

画面ロックですが、**ユーザーが画面にタッチしても反応しない**という条件にするのであれば
ボタンなどの使用しないアプリにすれば良いと思います。

また、アプリから起動時iOSのロック画面の呼び出しはできません。
ホームボタンを無効化する場合はキオスクモードにする必要があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。アプリからロック状態にすることは不可能なんですね。参考になりました。